Looking for the name of a movie featuring a job interview scene involving a flaming tie.
Okay. There has been a movie stuck in my brain for a while that is torturing me because I can't remember what it was.
The film shows a guy going in for an interview for a job. The interviewer asks him to sell him a glass of water. 
So, the interviewee takes a lighter, grabs his neck tie and lights it on fire. As the guy is freaking out, he sells him the glass of water.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? You might also want to use a slightly more descriptive title.

Yes, please add as many details as you can possibly remember since I think I know what you're after (and it's not a movie), but need to make sure.

I'm from the US. I remember watching it on TV several months ago. I really don't remember much beyond that once scene. It's quite frustrating.

There is a British TV show called Skins (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skins_(UK_TV_series) that had a scene very much like that, only involving tea instead of water.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EaA2scfnl0

@pooter03 YOU ARE MY HERO! That is EXACTLY it! THANK YOU! Please write it up as an answer.

As confirmed by @AversaS, it is the British TV show Skins.   
The scene in question can be viewed here

TV show, Skins. 
Chris gets a job selling houses:



